How to build a CSV output that can count when a repeat is added PowerShell
Working on building a script to export to a continued CSV file that counts when an IP is added more than once. The script will add the IP to a new line but the 'Total' count will go up by 1 each time it is added.
$IP = @()
foreach ($test in $IPs) {
  $IP += [PSCustomObject]@{
    IP                 = "$($test.IP)"
    Total              = $null 
  }
}

$IP = $IP | Sort-Object -Property 'IP'
$IP | Export-CSV -Path $file 

This is what I have built to export to a CSV file. I want to keep adding hosts to this CSV file when the script is run but simply add the counter to the 'Total' column.

Use a hashtable to keep track of previously seen IP addresses:
# create hashtable to keep track of seen IP addresses
$IPCounts = @{}

$IP = foreach ($test in $IPs) {
  # stringify IP address, we'll reuse the same string throughout
  $ipAddress = "$($test.IP)"

  if (-not $IPCounts.ContainsKey($ipAddress)) {
    # IP address has not been observed previously, record a count of 0
    $IPCounts[$ipAddress] = 0
  }

  # output object with running count for the given IP address
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    IP    = $ipAddress
    Total = ++$IPCounts[$ipAddress]
  }
}

$IP |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation

The ++ prefix operator will increment the value stored in $IPCounts[$ipAddress] and output the incremented value.

If you simply want an aggregated count of each distinct IP address observed, use Group-Object:
$IPs |Group-Object -Property IP -NoElement |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation


there are a few ways to do this, mostly depending on how many IP you expect to add\how often
here an example:
# Let's load the CSV as a List, so we can easily add elements to it later.   
[System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]$CsvContents = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath


# Loop through the list of IP to add.   
foreach ($Ip in $IpList) {

    # Count how many instances of the IP are in the List.   
    # Casted to [int] so if there is no result because it's the first time it becomes 0.   
    [int]$Count = $CsvContents | 
        Where-Object -Property ipaddress -EQ $Ip | 
        Measure-Object | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

    # Add the IP and the count, increased by 1, as a PSCustomObject to the List.  
    $CsvContents.add([pscustomobject]@{ipaddress = $Ip; Count = $Count + 1 })

}

# At the end of the loop, export back to the CSV.   
$CsvContents | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

